# Convert Portable Kitty session to registry Kitty session

Tags: ssh, kitty

I've set up about 30 ssh sessions in Kitty's portable version.  I would like to apply themes to my terminals which is much simpler by going through the registry.

Do you know a way to convert portable Kitty sessions (kitty.ini savemode=dir) to Kitty (kitty.ini savemode=registry)

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Run `kitty.exe -convert-reg` and you'll find all sessions (previously saved as files) in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\9bis.com\KiTTY`.